# Typescript autoconverting number to string when creating object

Tags: angular, typescript, http, http-post

I have a generic sort of function, which takes in fields (class properties) and creates a POST request out of it.

code is something like this:

```
public state: number;

updateField(field: string | number, name: string, team: boolean = true) {
  this.http.post('/update_key', {
        [path]: { [name]: field }
  })
}
```

> Here `path` is a variable with a firebase path like `/ipl_data/match_info/current_match`

I call this like `this.updateField(this.state, 'state', false);`

When this request is sent, the request body is created like:

```
{
  "/ipl_data/match_info/current_match": {
    "state":"3"
  }          ^------ this should be a number since type was defined as number
}
```

Is there a way to tackle this situation?

Comment: `[path]: { [name]: +field }` the `+variable` will hard cast it as a number

Comment: Replace updateField(field: string | number, name: string, team: boolean = true) ===> updateField(field: string | number, name: number, team: boolean = true) or updateField(field: string | number, name: any, team: boolean = true)

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i've tried that and it works. But as you must have guessed from function signature that field has union type of `string | number`. Hard casting to number would work in this case, but what about ones where I need it as a string. That is what I expect typescript to keep check for me when I'm defining type on my variables?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing it as a string or as a number, in those cases?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
updateField(field: string | number, name: string, team: boolean = true) {
  this.http.post('/update_key', {
        [path]: { [name]: !isNaN(field) ? +field : field }
  })
}
```

Comment: It seems to always go to the else condition. I still get `"3"`

Comment: Typescript is always passing the field as a string. I tried this with a `console.log` at the top of the function with `typeof`. Has it got something to do with the way I've defined my argument type `string | number` i.e. a union type? So it tried to auto-cast to the biggest type?

Comment: I updated my answer, so if `field` is a number inside the string, eg. `'3'`, it is converted to a number, otherwise it is left as is. Might do what you want in most cases... Alternative can be to add a parameter to your function telling explicitly if `field` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your `this.state === "3"` in the first place. Check the place where `this.state` got assigned a value.

This is more of a "javascript" problem rather than a "typescript" one. You need to understand that typescript has **zero** impact on the runtime behavior of your code, it only works in your IDE and when you compile the code.

Comment: I have an input element bound to state with [(ngModel)] and type="number"

Comment: AFAIK, with native HTML input, even when type="number", `input.value` is still string type. That's what the spec says. You need to confirm that, when set `type="number"`, angular will automatically convert string value to number for you.

Comment: I've mostly used angular's reactive forms in this project for most cases, they define the `FormControl` with a particular type like `new FormControl(0, Validators.Required)` and never experienced such an issue. I guess FormControl provides additional checks over types to make sure such bugs never pop up. This might be the reason I ran into this bug for the first time.

Comment: @IshanKhare Sorry, i'm not an angular expert, can't help with that. I can only tell you this issue has nothing to do with typescript.